# how to show java console

Tags: java, console

Is it possible to get java console shown while starting java application outside of command prompt?

I have tried following settings:

Windows, Java Control Panel -> Advanced :

- Java console: Show Console, selected,
- Miscellaneous: Place Java icon in system tray, checked

but these does not seem to work.

Comment: No, I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: You go on Windows than of show Perspective and than of show console, it's easy, but I don't know that it was show perspektive ore perspektive ore reset perspektive, one of this things is it (Sorry my english is not the best).